# Why explicitly target net6.0 with netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, csproj, .net-standard-2.0

I'm new to .NET world and would like to know what is the difference between the two statements:

1. `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`
2. `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`

As I know netstandard2.0 covers the net6.0, what makes us mention it again in the TargetFrameworks ??

Comment: You may find this instructive https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#when-to-target-net50-or-net60-vs-netstandard

Comment: _"As I know netstandard2.0 covers the net6.0"_ - I would argue that this is other way around, .net6.0 is superset of .netstandard .

Answer (score 4):

It means that in some places in your code you can use conditional compilation to specify .NET-6-specific types/methods etc.

We do exactly this in my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) project, for example.

The [project file](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/main/src/NodaTime/NodaTime.csproj) targets netstandard2.0 and net6.0:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And then we have a [`DateOnlyExtensions` class](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/main/src/NodaTime/Extensions/DateOnlyExtensions.cs) which is only present in the .NET 6 build, for `DateOnly` (which was only introduced in .NET 6.0):

```cs
#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER

// Code using DateOnly

#endif
```

Likewise in `LocalDate` we have `ToDateOnly` and `FromDateOnly` methods which are only included in the .NET 6 build.